# Python error: io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm running a python code, The code is:

```
f = open("File.txt", "r")
f.write("my first file\n")
f.write("my second file \n\n")
f.write("contains three lines\n")
f.read(2)
```

but I'm keeping have an error:

```
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
PS F:\ping> python -u "f:\ping\file.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "f:\ping\file.py", line 2, in <module>
f.write("my first file\n")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You open the file in read mode.
Change the `"r"` to `"w"`.

```
f = open("File.txt", "w")
```